# close open application before to relaunch from notification panel?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I am using Intent to relaunch app from **Notification Panel**, but before to launch new instance how can close existing same open app, no matter in which state application is.

Any idea/suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` when you create the `Intent` to launch your app.

NOTE: However, this will only work if your root `Activity` is still present in the task (ie: you didn't call `finish()` on it when starting any other `Activity` in your task.

Comment: Thanks...will give a try..but with it app is playing with multiple scenario :)

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple scenario"?

Comment: notification can raise over any screen of application, so that time it will tough to maintain state...let's say if control is over Some A screen then it should be there, if it's on Screen B..then it should redirect to parent of B..like this.

Comment: The code in my answer will remove all activities from the task and basically start your application all over again from the beginning. Regardless of the current state of your application. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Heyy David...as u mention "this will only work if your root Activity is still present in the task" ...so with this app have some other cases.

Comment: I see. well, you can try to fix the app so that the root activity doesn't finish when it starts other activities

Answer (score 0):

Use have to use some flag, this might help u

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Also check your manifest for the

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

attribute on the activity which launches from the notification.

Comment: I used Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP ..but it's same...open activity remain as it is...n new intent activity get lauch